# Windows application stops working when I restart MySQL

Tags: c#, mysql

I have developed a Windows application in c#.net with MySQL.
MySQL is on another server.
I had installed application on to client machine.  It works also, but the problem comes when I restart MySQL.
The application doesn't get host address and when I change IP address of client machine it started working.
Everytime when I restart mysql server this problem occurs.

Connection string is as follows:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8" ?>
<configuration>

  <connectionStrings>
    <add name="MyConn" connectionString="server=ip address of my server; user id=uid; password=pwd; database=root; pooling=false" providerName="MySql.Data.MySqlClient"/>
  </connectionStrings>
</configuration>
```

Can anyone tell me how to resolve it?

Comment: Is your application working when you restart your MySql server?

Comment: that is the main problem.if i restart i could not login into it.if i change ip address of client machine then it works

Comment: I mean is your application being executed (has the status of a working process) , when you restart your MySQL server ?

Comment: yes it is working .problem occurs only when u restart it.After i restart if i would login then it gives error like invalid connection.

Comment: even if i change ip of another pc  as that client's ip then also it start but not on that pc after running on other pc with d same ip it work on that client machine again.

Comment: gor eg. client machine 1 having ip "xx:xx:xx:xx" when it stop working for my application i change ip of another machine (client machine two) as "xx:xx:xx:xx" and it works then again i keep the ip of machine 1 as xx:xx:xx:xx and it gets stared..another way is if i change client machine 1's ip to yy:yy:yy:yy

Comment: is there any solution for this

Comment: How are you connecting to the MySQL Server from the windows app?  Are you opening a connection upon start and leaving it open for the duration of the application?  Or are you opening/closing connections as you need them?

Comment: Is the application maintaining a handle to the database or is it opening handles when needed and closing them when done? It sounds like you're dealing with a stale database handle due to the server restarting but the application still trying to use its old connection.

Answer (score 0):

It sounds like you have a refresh issue related to C# application.  The program loses the connection when MySQL is restarted and then it doesn't try again until the network change (change IP) on the client machine brings the connection back to life again.

I would recommend either a timer that will check at a periodic interval to see if the server is back or some user initiated event that re-attempts connection.